# next_permutation of vector of strings is skipping one permutation

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print all permutations of a vector of strings. This code works as intended:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v;

    v.push_back("+1");
    v.push_back("x4");

    do {
        cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << endl;
    } while (next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
}
```

Output:

```
+1 x4
x4 +1
```

But when I change "x4" for "*4" the next_pemutation loop iterates only one time.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v;

    v.push_back("+1");
    v.push_back("*4");

    do {
        cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << endl;
    } while (next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
}
```

Output:

```
+1 *4
```

Other characters like # seems to have the same effect. Why is it happening?

Comment: It needs to start sorted to go through all of them.

Comment: "Next" means "next in a specific ordering of all permutations".

Comment: In fact, please explain to us first which part of [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) you don't understand, so we can give a useful answer.

Comment: `std::next_permutation` returns true if the new permutation is lexicographically greater than the previous one

Comment: @KerrekSB the documentation is clear, I'm new to c++ and didn't knew were it was and was learning through examples, I'll look on the documentation next time, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm needs to start with a sorted `vector` to print all permutations:

`"+1" < "x4"` (`'+' < 'x'`): so you really begin with the "first" permutation.
`"+1" > "*4"` (`'+' > '*'`): So you don't begin with the first permutation.

See man ascii to have the order of `char` (ascii is the most popular one, but platforms can use other as EBCDIC though).

To solve your problem, you may do after the last `push_back`:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```